# How do I reference an element that is to be returned by a React component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, element, ref

I want to start out by telling you that I am new to react and I come from a background of working almost entirely with vanilla JS and HTML.
I want to know how to reference/pass an element as an argument in a function similar to how you would go about it in JS:

```
const myElement = document.getElementById("my-element");
```

or

```
const myElement = document.createElement("div");
function testFunc(element) {
return element.getBoundingClientRect();
}
testFunc(myElement);
```

I have googled a bit but haven't found any good answers, all I could find was about "ref" but I am sure there is a simpler solution.

This is what I have in React now:

```
import React from "react";
import "./myComp.css";

function myComp(props) {
  const sliderContainer = (
    <div className="slider-container" style={props.styles}></div>
  );

  function myFunc(element) {
      return element.getBoundingClientRect();
  }

  const elementDimensions = myFunc(sliderContainer);

  return { sliderContainer };
}

export default myComp;
```

But what i want to do is:

```
import React from "react";
import "./myComp.css";

function myComp(props) {
  const sliderContainer = "slider-container" //SOME SORT OF REFRENCE / SELECTOR, I'VE FIGURED OUT THAT querySelectors IS NOT THE RIGHT APPORACH

  function myFunc(element) {
      return element.getBoundingClientRect();
  }

  const elementDimensions = myFunc(sliderContainer);

  return (
    <div className="slider-container" style={props.styles}>
        <div className="myChild"></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default myComp;
```

Comment: You may be asking an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info). You might instead ask how to handle your actual problem, rather than asking about your proposed solution. That said, refs are a common strategy to reference elements in React.

Comment: Did you come across to the `useRef` hook. You can assign `ref={}` to the jsx. You can read [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html) for more info.

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect such a quick response. So I suppose refs are the way to go after all?

Comment: @Odjuret Definitely.

Comment: @isherwood I understand what you mean but this code is purely for demonstration's sake, I just used "getBoundingClientRect()" as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
const sliderContainer = useRef(null);

function myFunc(element) {
  return element.getBoundingClientRect();
}

useEffect(() => {
  const elementDimensions = myFunc(sliderContainer.current);
});

return (
  <div ref={sliderContainer} className="slider-container" style={props.styles}>
      <div className="myChild"></div>
  </div>
);
```

The `ref` property will assign the element to `sliderContainer.current` once the component has been mounted.

Note that the value is initially set to be null: `useRef(null)`.

You must wait until the element is not null before accessing it as the element will not yet be mounted when the component is initially rendered.

Comment: @Odjuret Great. No problem.

Answer (score 1):

in React you can use

```
document.getElementById('id-object');
```

or

```
document.querySelector('object-class');
```

But you can find more info in this [article](https://medium.com/the-clever-dev/using-queryselector-and-queryselectorall-with-modern-javascript-frameworks-a20b462c1d3b) on Medium.

Hope that this was useful!

Comment: Those are just plain JavaScript methods. They'd require that you know the ID or class name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementById('slider-container');` or any other use of `document` in React.

Comment: It is worth noting that this method requires waiting until the component has been mounted, otherwise the element won't yet exist.